# outputting values from a strong array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I have an array of strings:

```
string names[] = { "MERCURY", "VENUS", "MOON", "MARS", "JUPITER", "SATURN", "URANUS", "NEPTUNE", "PLUTO" }; //names of the planets in order
```

I am trying to print one value out like this:

```
cout << names[place];
```

place is an integer.

It gives me an error when i try "no operator "<<" matches these operands" any ideas? i have tried using a number instead of a variable.

Comment: You probably forgot to `#include <string>`.

Comment: [Cannot Reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/36ef4eac13925e33)

Comment: You probably forgot to `#include <iostream>`

Comment: Please post more code so we don't have to guess.

Comment: What is a strong array?

Comment: Would be helpful if you show us the minimal code that reproduce that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you probably forgot to include the `<string>` error. This may have happened because you included a wrong header, such as `<string.h>`, completely different from `<string>`. (For C-style strings)